# sql set values for some variables with a select

Tags: sql

I have something like this

```
declare @foo bigint;
declare @bar nvarchar(20);

set @foo = select foo from theTable where id = 37;
set @bar = select bar from theTable whre id = 37;
```

is it possible to do this with a single select ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  @foo = foo,
        @bar = bar
FROM    theTable
WHERE   id = 37
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible if you use the SET command  .. but if you use SELECT, you can do it.

```
SELECT @foo = foo, @bar = bar FROM theTable where id = 37
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in a single sql query using:

```
SELECT @bar = bar, @foo = foo from theTable whre id = 37;
```